# For loop to check the first letter in an array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use a for loop to loop through an array and check the first letter of each word in the array and check to see if it starts with an M, but I can't seem to figure out how to correctly set that up.

So far I have this:

```
for (var animalsName = cats[0]; animalsName <= cats; animalsName++){
    if (animalsName.charAt(0) == 'M') {
        console.log("No treat for " + animalsName + ".");
    } else {
        console.log(animalsName + " loved their treat!");
    }
}
```

Comment: `animalsName` seems like it would be a string so I'm curious what you expect `animalsName++` to do. Maybe just read some basic "for loop" tutorial like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp).

Comment: Yeah, i figured it wouldn't do anything but I'm not sure on how to increment a string.

Comment: "_I'm not sure on how to increment a string_" That's because you don't. You increment some sort of number and use that to get strings from your array.

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Comment: The tutorial I linked to in my first comment has examples, that's what the tutorials are for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are very close.

I have made minor change in the for loop to iterate correctly and fetch the first character of the animal name.

```js
var cats = [];
cats.push('mname1');
cats.push('tname1');
cats.push('mname2');
cats.push('Mname3');


for (var index = 0; index < cats.length; index++){

    var animalsName = cats[index];
    
    if (animalsName.substr(0,1).toLowerCase() === 'm') {
        console.log("No treat for " + animalsName + ".");
    } else {
        console.log(animalsName + " loved their treat!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why downvote? I see that my answer is copied and pasted as a separate answer and marked as working solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
for (let i = 0; i < cats.length; i += 1) {
  if (cats[i].charAt(0).toLowerCase() === 'm') {
    // do whatever you want
  }
}
```

This will loop over the `cats` array and check the first letter--`charAt(0)`--of each element in the array. If the first letter, converted to lower case, is 'm', then you do whatever you want.